# meteor on Windows: cannot deploy app: ReferenceError: rpc_callback is not defined

Tags: meteor

Just downloaded [meteor for Windows](http://win.meteor.com/) created the app `studyapp`, started the server locally - and it works, then trying to deploy it on their server: `meteor deploy studyapp.meteor.com`, However:

```
C:\work\meteor-study\studyapp>meteor deploy studyapp.meteor.com
Deploying to studyapp.meteor.com.  Bundling ... uploading ...
C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\app\meteor\deploy.js:147
    var rpc = meteor_rpc('deploy', 'POST', site, opts, rpc_callback);
                                                       ^
ReferenceError: rpc_callback is not defined
    at ChildProcess.bundle_and_deploy (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\app\me
teor\deploy.js:147:56)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
    at Process._handle.onexit (child_process.js:678:10)
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE: I noticed that now a new folder appeared under `myapp/.meteor/local/build_tar/..` it has `bundle` in it. `built_tar` (having `tar` in it) doesn't sound Windows-friendly, does it mean it's not possible to deploy from Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @TomWijsman its the bug that was introduced and will be fixed by version 0.5.3
Bug report/status is [here](https://github.com/TomWij/meteor/issues/45)